# Неправильно работает численное интегрирование методом Гаусса

Tags: c++, математика

Необходимо было разработать программу нахождения значения определенного интеграла с помощью метода Гаусса. Функция для интегрирования и интервал интегрирования приведены ниже

Информация по методу Гаусса была взята отсюда:

http://ums.physics.usu.ru/st/NUM_03.PDF

http://aco.ifmo.ru/el_books/numerical_methods/lectures/glava2_3.html

`y = cos(x)·(x +1)^–1 + 2x` [1;25]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define n 3

using namespace std;

double f(double x)
{
    return cos(x)*(1./(x+1))+2*x;
}

double Gauss(double a, double b)
{
    double Xi[n]={-0.7745967,0,0.7745967};
    double Ci[n]={0.5555556,0.8888889,0.5555556};
    double ra=(b-a)/2;
    double su=(a+b)/2;
    double Q, S, I;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        Q=su+ra*Xi[i-1];
        S=Ci[i-1]*f(Q);
    }
    I=ra*S;
    return I;
}

int main()
{
    double a;
    double b;
    cout<<"vvedite a"<<endl;
    cin>>a;
    cout<<"vvedite b"<<endl;
    cin>>b;
    cout<<"I = "<<Gauss(a,b);

    return 0;
}
```

Выводится неверный ответ 278.025, хотя Wolfram и остальные онлайн калькуляторы высчитывают 623.7358

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Начнем с того, что в цикле

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    Q=su+ra*Xi[i-1];
    S=Ci[i-1]*f(Q);
}
```

чему у вас равно `Xi[-1]` и `Ci[-1]` - ну, при `i=0`?

Далее - вычисленные для `i=0` и `i=1` значения вы просто выбрасываете. Вообще. Зачем тогда их вообще считать? :)

Дальше спрашивать или достаточно? :)

P.S. Только считать на таком диапазоне - [1;25] - по всего трем точкам - тихий бред. получите что-то *похожее* на ответ, но не более того. Конечно, не в три раза отличие, но... Вам нужно разбивать весь интервал на меньшие отрезки, а уже потом на каждом меньшем отрезке применять формулу Гаусса.

P.P.S. Ладно, предрождественская распродажа :) Держите...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
const int n = 3;
const int N = 100;

using namespace std;

double f(double x)
{
    return cos(x)*(1./(x+1))+2*x;
}

double Gauss(double a, double b)
{
    const double Xi[n]={-0.7745967,0,0.7745967};
    const double Ci[n]={0.5555556,0.8888889,0.5555556};

    double ra=(b-a)/2;
    double su=(a+b)/2;
    double Q, S = 0.0;
    for(int i=0;i < n; i++)
    {
        Q = su+ra*Xi[i];
        S += Ci[i]*f(Q);
    }
    return ra*S;
}

int main()
{
    double a = 1.0;
    double b = 25.0;
    double s = 0.0;
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        s += Gauss(a+i*(b-a)/N, a+(i+1)*(b-a)/N);
    }
    cout << "I = " << s << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: большое спасибо, вы очень добры)

Comment: Есть у меня такой недостаток - сначала увлекаюсь и решаю, а потом жаба давит выкинуть :)

Comment: поверьте, это не недостаток! Вы спасли мою курсовую